# Copy data from blob storage to sqlDatabase (into multiple tables)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i am relatively new to azure and I found myself stuck! I am trying to read data from my blob storage into SQL database using Azure DataFactory. I got this process to work fine using copy activity, now I am trying to insert the data into multiple tables which relate to each other somehow (privateKey, foreignKey). **For example, to updated the Table CAR I need to know if the owner exists in the Table Owner**. And I am not able to find a detailed explanation on how to go about it! Anyone with some experience to give me some guidance? thanks

Comment: Did you consider to use stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach to solving this problem.  Using the code below, we can merge data from multiple files, all with a similar name, into a data frame and push the whole thing into SQL Server.  This is Scala, so it needs to be run in your Azure Databricks environment.

```
# merge files with similar names into a single dataframe
val DF = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/corp/ABC*.gz")


DF.count()


# rename headers in dataframe
val newNames = Seq("ID", "FName", "LName", "Address", "ZipCode", "file_name")
val dfRenamed = df.toDF(newNames: _*)

dfRenamed.printSchema


# push the dataframe to sql server
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"            -> "my_sql_server.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"   -> "my_db_name",
  "dbTable"        -> "dbo.my_table",
  "user"           -> "xxxxx",
  "password"       -> "xxxxx",
  "connectTimeout" -> "5", //seconds
  "queryTimeout"   -> "5"  //seconds
))

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(config)
```

The code above will read every line of every file.  If the headers are in the first line, this works great.  If the headers and NOT in the first line, use the code below to crate a specific schema, and again, read every line of every file.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("field1", StringType, true),
    StructField("field2", StringType, true),
    StructField("field3", StringType, true),
    StructField("field4", StringType, true),
    StructField("field5", StringType, true),
    StructField("field6", StringType, true),
    StructField("field7", StringType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("sep", "|")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("mnt/rawdata/corp/ABC*.gz")
    .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())


import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._



val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).
//df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig, bulkCopyMetadata)
//df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig) if no metadata is specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a Join or a Lookup using Mapping Data Flows and then redirect rows to the appropriate database tables using the Conditional Split transformation.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to use lookup activity to get table names and then use forEach activity to traverse through the tables and then use Mapping data flow or Databricks to apply filters and joins

Answer (score 0):

I could add to what Shivar had called out . We will have to use the lookup activity , but you should make sure the the table "Owner" is copied first before you work on the CAR table , to do this you should enable the sequential option in foreach activity so that the follow the order , otherwise you will a lot of FK violation error .